# MySQL: Slow schema updates on empty tables with InnoDB

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a collection of scripts for migrating my DB schema to the latest version. For developments and testing I regularly apply them all at once, operating on empty tables since there is no data.

This process is painfully slow since we started using InnoDB. A single alter table operation takes ~0.1s with MyISAM but ~0.5s with InnoDB. I tried disabling foreign key checks, but it doesn't help much. Is there anything else I can try to speed things up?

(I tried creating the schema using MyISAM and migrating it but this way I lose foreign keys.)

Answer (score 0):

The default values for innoDB are shockingly guant.  If you give the my.cnf reasonable values, it may well speed up InnoDB in general, and may have a positive impact on schema updates too.

Comment: Any suggestions on what settings should I look at?